# Generic base class method for handling service calls in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, ecmascript-6

**Target:**
a generic method which calls a web service throgh my Network class shows spinner meanwhile remove it once completed, then finally handles error if any by showing alert otherwise send back the response into my calling class.

**What I have done:** 
I have written following method i.e. in my base class and all classes will have this method.

**Problem:**
As the setState is called which updates the screen hence any of the alert (error/success) which comes for a moment and then the last screen comes in front and every thing stuck as the alert is behind the screen.

**Require**:
Can anyone points me what mistake I am doing or any concept how to handle this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Network from './Network';

export default class BaseClass extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         spinner:false,
         response:''
      }
   }

  onPress(data){
      this.setState({ spinner: true })

      var net = new Network();
      net.makeCall(data,function(context,err,res){
      context.setState({ spinner: false })

      if(err!= null){
       alert('error')
      }
      else{
         alert('sccess')
      }
      )
     }
}
```

**2nd Approach**
I have adopted this second approach but getting same results here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { View } from 'react-native'
    import Network from './Network';

    export default class BaseClass extends Component {
       constructor() {
          super()
          this.state = {
             spinner:false,
             response:''
          }
       }

      onPress(data){
          this.setState({ spinner: true })

          var net = new Network();
          net.makeCall(data,function(context,err,res){
          context.setState({ spinner: false })

          if(err!= null){
           context.setState({ response: err })
          }
          else{
             context.setState({ response: data })
          }
          )
       }

    componentDidUpdate(){
    alert(this.state.response)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current working class , few classes are custom classes like Screens,SessionManager,SessionTimer,Constants

```
"use strict";
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
import Pinch from 'react-native-pinch';
import Config from './Config'
import {SessionManager} from './utilities/SessionManager';
import Constants from './utilities/Constants'
import {Platform, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Screens} from './navigation/Screens'
import SessionTimer from './utilities/SessionTimer';
import IMEI from './utilities/IMEI'
// Check Device Info
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');

//import Spinner from  'react-native-spinkit'

/*
 this class will be used to communicate with
 server and getting url params from the calling class,
 handles the server error if there is no error it will
 return the repsonse to the calling class
 */
export class WebServiceCallManager extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: this.props.visible,
            size: 100,
        }
    }

    callWebService(requestAction, subAction, bodyParams, responseHandler, optionalErrHandler) {
        this.setState({visible: true});//Starting the Processing indicator
        let imei = null;
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            imei = SessionManager.getSessionValue("IMEI");
        }

        var params = {
            "Header": {
                "AppVersion": DeviceInfo.getVersion(),
                //"IMEI":imei,
                //"DEVICE_MAKE" : (Platform.OS === 'android') ?  "AN": (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "IP" : "OT",
                "Channel": (Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'MOBILE_ANDROID' : (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "MOBILE_IOS" : null,
                // DeviceInfo.getManufacturer()
                //    "Channel":DeviceInfo.getManufacturer(),
                //"DeviceId": DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
                //  "NetworkType": "MOBILE DATA 3G",
                "RequestAction": requestAction,
                "SubAction": subAction,
                "Token": SessionManager.getSessionValue(Constants.TOKEN),
                //  "Operator": "ZONG",
                "CSRF": SessionManager.getSessionValue(Constants.CSRF),
                //"OS": DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion(),
                "DeviceInformation": {
                    "IMEI": imei,
                    "Manufacturer": DeviceInfo.getManufacturer(),
                    "Model": DeviceInfo.getModel(),
                    "DeviceId": DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
                    "DeviceMake": (Platform.OS === 'android') ? "AN" : (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "IP" : "OT",
                    "OS": DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion(),
                }

            },
            "Body": {
                "Transaction": bodyParams
            }
        };

        var url = Config.IP;

        if (url.startsWith('https')) {
            this._httpsCalling(url, params, responseHandler, optionalErrHandler);
        } else {
            this._httpCalling(url, params, responseHandler, optionalErrHandler);
        }
    }

    _httpsCalling(url, params, responseHandler) {
        Pinch.fetch(url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(params),
                sslPinning: {
                    cert: 'prodcer'
                }
            })
            .then((responseResult) => {
                this.setState({visible: false});// removing the Processing symbol
                var result = JSON.parse(responseResult.bodyString);
                var strResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                if (responseResult.status == '0') {
                    responseHandler(strResult);
                }
                else {
                    responseHandler(strResult);

                }
            }).catch((err) => {
            this.setState({visible: false});// removing the Processing symbol
            responseHandler(err.message + '');
        })
            .done();
    }

    _httpCalling(url, params, responseHandler, optionalErrHandler) {
        fetch(url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(params)

            })
            .then((resType) => resType.json())
            .then((responseResult) => {
                let timer = new SessionTimer();
                timer.resetSessionTimer(0);
                this.setState({visible: false});// removing the Processing symbol
                SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.TOKEN, responseResult.Header.Cookie);
                SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.CSRF, responseResult.Header.CSRF);
                if (responseResult.Header.ResponseCode == '0') {

                    responseHandler(responseResult);
                }
                else {
                    if (optionalErrHandler !== undefined) {
                        optionalErrHandler(responseResult.Header);
                    }
                    this.errorHandler(responseResult.Header);
                    // responseHandler(null ,responseResult.Header.ResponseMessage);

                }
            }).catch((err) => {

            var error = {ResponseMessage: err.message};

            if (optionalErrHandler !== undefined) {
                optionalErrHandler(error);
            }

            this.errorHandler(error);
        })
            .done();
    }

    errorHandler(errorData) {

        this.setState({visible: false});// removing the Processing symbol

        let msg = errorData.ResponseMessage;
        let errorCode = errorData.ResponseCode;

        if (errorCode == 111) {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    Alert.alert('Respose Error ' +
                        msg,
                        '',
                        [
                            {
                                text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
                                this.props.nav.popToRoute(Screens.LoginScreen)
                            }
                            },
                        ],
                        {cancelable: false}
                    )
                },
                100
            );
        }
        else {

            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    alert(msg)
                },
                100
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Spinner visible={this.state.visible} itemProp='size:100'/>
    }
}
```

**EDIT 16 Sep 2019:**

Here I am adding another class where I have made use of my network class defined above, actually its a component in React world so inside render method we have added this component and got reference of that component upon which we are calling a method `callWebService()`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {  StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,Switch, Alert, Image, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions, Platform,AppState } from 'react-native';
import Constants from '.././utilities/Constants'
import {Screens} from '.././navigation/Screens'
import {ScreenClass} from '.././navigation/Screens';
import TextInputCustom from '.././components/TextInputCustom';
import {SessionManager} from '../utilities/SessionManager';
import {WebServiceCallManager} from '.././WebServiceCallManager';
import {NavigationManager} from '.././navigation/NavigationManager';
import Fingerprint from '.././fingerprint/FingerprintAndroid';


const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard');
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
let opacity = 1;
// source address of login background image
const loginBackgroundViewImg = require('.././assets/login_box.png');
const biometricImage = require('.././assets/biometric_icon.png');

var langs = new Constants(); // language localization


/* Login View for displaying TextInputs(username, passwords),
   Buttons (Login, Register) and Labels (Terms & condition , forget password)
*/

export class LoginContainer extends Component {
     constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            username: '' , // user33
            password: '', // Awaqas@2
            emptyInputFields : '',
            falseSwitchIsOn : true,
            phase: 'normal',
            message: '',
            cancelled: false
          }
     }



     componentDidMount() {
      //  Fingerprint.saveCredentials("user33","Awaqas@2",()=>{
      //   this.setState({
      //       phase: 'saved',
      //       message: ''
      //   });
      //  },()=>{});

            this.authenticate();

             AppState.addEventListener("change", async(state) => {
                 try {
                     if(state === "active" && await Fingerprint.isAuthenticationCanceled()) {
                         this.authenticate()
                     }
                 }
                 catch(z) {
                     console.error(z)
                 }
             })
         }

         async componentWillUnmount() {
             try {
                 if(!Fingerprint.isAuthenticationCanceled()) {
                     //stop listening to authentication.
                     await Fingerprint.cancelAuthentication();
                 }
             } catch(z) {
                 console.error(z);
             }
         }

         async authenticate() {

             try {
                 // do sanity checks before starting authentication flow.
                 // HIGHLY recommended in real life usage. see more on why you should do this in the readme.md
                 const hardware = await Fingerprint.isHardwareDetected();
                 const permission = await Fingerprint.hasPermission();
                 const enrolled = await Fingerprint.hasEnrolledFingerprints();

                 if (!hardware || !permission || !enrolled) {
                     let message = !enrolled ? 'No fingerprints registered.' : !hardware ? 'This device doesn\'t support fingerprint scanning.' : 'App has no permission.'
                     this.setState({
                         phase: 'fail',
                         message
                     });
                     return;
                 }

                  await Fingerprint.authenticate(warning => {
                     this.setState({
                         phase: 'warn',
                         message: warning.message
                     })
                 });

                 // if we got this far, it means the authentication succeeded.
                 this.setState({
                     phase: 'success',
                     message: ''
                 });

                 // in real life, we'd probably do something here (process the payment, unlock the vault, whatever)
                 // but this is a demo. so restart authentication.
                // setTimeout(() => this.authenticate(), 3000);

             } catch (error) {
                 if(error.code == Fingerprint.FINGERPRINT_ERROR_CANCELED) {
                     // we don't show this error to the user.
                     // we will check if the auth was cancelled & restart the flow when the appstate becomes active again.
                     return;
                 }
                 this.setState({
                     phase: 'fail',
                     message: error.message
                 })
             }
         }

      buttonsHandler(type){
          switch (type) {
               case 'forgotpassword':
                    this.props.navigation.push(Screens.ForgotPasswordScreen);
                    break;
               case 'forgotuserid':
                this.props.navigation.push(Screens.ForgotUserIDScreen);
                    break;
               case 'unlockprofile':
                this.props.navigation.push(Screens.UnlockProfileScreen);
                    break;
              case 'register':
                  dismissKeyboard();
                  this.props.navigation.push(Screens.RegistrationWelcomeScreen);
                  break;
               case 'login':
                    this.loginWebServiceCall();
                    break;
               default:
                     alert(type + ' is pressed');

          }
    }


    // this will be called when user hit login button

    loginWebServiceCall()
    {

         if(this.state.username.length === 0 &&  this.state.password.length === 0){
            this.setState({emptyInputFields:langs.strings.login_userid_password_empty});
            this.userName.textFocus();
         }
         else if (this.state.username.length === 0 ) {
           this.setState({emptyInputFields:langs.strings.login_userid_empty});
           this.userName.textFocus();
         }
         else if ( this.state.password.length === 0) {
           this.setState({emptyInputFields:langs.strings.login_password_empty});
           this.password.textFocus();

         }else{
              this.setState({emptyInputFields:''});
              var params = {
                   "Password": this.state.password,
                   "UserName": this.state.username,
                   "LoginType": 'Manual',
              };

              this.webservicemanager.callWebService("LOGIN","TRANSACTION",params,(response) => {this.handleWebServiceCallResponse(response);});
         }
    }

    /* handle the web service successfull response error
    response will be handled inside WebServiceCallManager */

    handleWebServiceCallResponse(data){

        dismissKeyboard();

        var userData = {
            "username":this.state.username,
            "password":this.state.password
        }
        var passwordPolicy = {
          "passwordPolicy" : data.Body.Transaction.PasswordPolicy,
          "passwordPolicyRegex" : data.Body.Transaction.PasswordPolicyRegex
        }

        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.FASTTRANSFER_BENEFICIARY_BRANCH_LIST,data.Body.Transaction.BranchList);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.BENEFICIARY_COUNTRY,data.Body.Transaction.CountryList);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.BENEFICIARY_RELATIONSHIP, data.Body.Transaction.RelationList);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.LOGIN_USERDATA, userData);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,data.Body.Transaction.CUSTNO);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.PASSWORD_POLICY, passwordPolicy);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue(Constants.SECURITY_QUESTIONS_LIST,data.Body.Transaction.Questions);
        var nextScreenName = data.Body.Transaction.NextScreenName;

        const SpecificScreenClass = ScreenClass.getClassFromClassName(nextScreenName);
        SessionManager.setSessionValue('nextScreenName', nextScreenName);
        this.props.navigation.push(SpecificScreenClass);


        this.setState({
             username:'',
             password:'',
             emptyInputFields:''
        });
        this.userName.textClear();
        this.password.textClear();
        dismissKeyboard();

    }

    // handling text input field focus
   textHandler(){
     this.password.focus();
   }

   onSwitchToggle(value){
     if(value){
        opacity = 1;
      }
     else{
       opacity= 0.4;
     }
     this.setState({falseSwitchIsOn: value});
   }

     render(){
       this.fetchCredentials(this.webservicemanager,this.handleWebServiceCallResponse.bind(this));

          return(
               <View style={ styles.loginView}>
                 <Image style={ styles.loginViewBackground} source={loginBackgroundViewImg}>


                 <View>

                   <TextInputCustom
                        ref ={(ref) => this.userName = ref}
                        placeholder={langs.strings.login_userid_placeholder}
                        secureTextEntry={false}
                        onChangeTextCallback={val => this.setState({'username' : val})}
                        returnKeyType="next"
                        textInputWidth = {((width*86)/100)}
                        // onEndEditingCallback = {() => this.password.textFocus()}
                   />

                   <TextInputCustom
                        ref ={(ref) => this.password =ref}
                        placeholder={langs.strings.login_password_placeholder}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeTextCallback={val => this.setState({'password' : val})}
                        returnKeyType="done"
                        textInputWidth = {((width*86)/100)}
                   />
                   <Text style={ styles.emptyInputFields}>{this.state.emptyInputFields}</Text>
                 </View>
                 <View style={ styles.middleContainerViewButtons}>
                   <View style={ styles.middleContainerViewButtonsBtn}>
                     <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.buttonsHandler('login')}>
                       <Text style={ styles.btnTextLabels}>{langs.strings.login_btnLogin}</Text>
                     </TouchableHighlight>
                   </View>
                   <View style={ styles.middleContainerViewButtonsBtn}>
                     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.buttonsHandler('register')}>
                       <Text style={ styles.btnTextLabels}>{langs.strings.login_btnRegister}</Text>
                     </TouchableHighlight>
                   </View>
                 </View>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.buttonsHandler('forgotpassword')}} underlayColor = {'transparent'}>
                   <Text style={ styles.labels} >
                     Forogot Password
                   </Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.buttonsHandler('forgotuserid')}} underlayColor = {'transparent'}>
                   <Text style={ styles.labels} >
                     Forogot User ID
                   </Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.buttonsHandler('terms')} underlayColor = {'transparent'}>
                   <View >
                     <Text style={ styles.labels}>
                       {langs.strings.login_txtTermsAndConditions}
                     </Text>
                   </View>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
                 <View style={styles.fingerPrintLayout}>
                 <TouchableHighlight  underlayColor = {'transparent'}>
                   <View >
                     <Image style={styles.biometricImage} source={biometricImage}/>
                   </View>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
                   <View style={styles.switchRow} >
                   <Text style={ styles.labels} >
                     Enable Finger Print Login
                   </Text>
                     <Switch
                     onValueChange={(value) => this.onSwitchToggle(value) }
                     style={styles.switchControl}
                     value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn} />
                   </View>
                   <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
                 </View>

               </Image>
               <WebServiceCallManager visible={false} nav = {this.props.navigation} ref={ (input) => {this.webservicemanager = input;}}/>
             </View>
          );
     }

      fetchCredentials(web,resHandler) {
       if(this.state.phase === 'success') {
        Fingerprint.fetchCredentials(
          (...res) => {
              console.log(res);
              var params = {
                  "Password": res[1],
                  "UserName": res[0],
                  "LoginType": 'Biometric'
             };
             this.setState({username:params.UserName,password:params.Password,phase:''})
             this.webservicemanager.callWebService("LOGIN","TRANSACTION",params,(response) => {this.handleWebServiceCallResponse(response);},
             (err)=> {
             this.authenticate();});
            },
            (res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return null;
              }
        );
     }
   }

} // end of class
```

Comment: and how to call the function? curious!

Comment: @RobinHood I have added the code where i have make use of my Network component, hope this will help you, you can directly go to loginWebServiceCall() method for usage